# .NET float representation in memory

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

According to [Jon Skeet's float article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx), setting the sign bit to 1 and everything else to 0 still gives the number 0. I'm not 100% sure if the sign bit is the very first bit (as told in the article) or the very last bit (as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.7.2)). Regardless, I tried both:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4];
buf[0] = 0b10000000;
buf[1] = 0b00000000;
buf[2] = 0b00000000;
buf[3] = 0b00000000;
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(buf, 0); // 1,793662E-43

buf[0] = 0b00000000;
buf[1] = 0b00000000;
buf[2] = 0b00000000;
buf[3] = 0b00000001;
float g = BitConverter.ToSingle(buf, 0); // 2,350989E-38
```

And both do not result in 0. What am I doing wrong? The sanity check of setting all bits to 0 works.

Comment: !again strikes Endianness

Comment: Thanx. That's the important hint.

Comment: Still, the .NET docs are telling me about the wrong bit order?! Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user EOF I realized that .NET bytes are not stored in the (for non-bit-hackers) intuitive endianess. `buf[3] = 0b10000000;` does the trick.

Comment: Only after two days have passed :)